# CSS not working after ajax replace

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

So on my website I got an CSS issue after AJAX replace. The purpose is to use AJAX to replace the current banner after a certain period of time, also the new banner will have a fade-in effect. AJAX and CSS fade-in effect work well individually, but when combining them together, AJAX still works (i.e. the new picture still loads) but there is no more fade-in effect.

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){getJSONData();});

    function getJSONData()
    {
    setTimeout("getJSONData()", 24000);
    $.getJSON('?act=rt&callback=?', displayData);
    }

    function displayData(dataJSON)
    {
    $("#randpic").html(dataJSON.randpic);
    }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<span id="randpic">
    <img alt="Hi" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="images/banner1.jpg" />
</span>
```

CSS code:

```
img {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

The PHP that Javascript calls will echo back something like this:

```
<img alt="Hi" onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="images/banner5.jpg" />
```

That should be all. Will add any other detail that you might find useful.
By the way, it's my first time asking a question here, if didn't do anything right, apologize in advance. Thanks.

Comment: As you're already using jQuery, why not just use `fadeIn(2000)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you change the HTML content ? It's src's attribute should be change. And more if you want a Fade effect you can use directly FadeIn() and FadeOut() jQuery's methods

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#randpic img').fadeIn();
    getJSONData();
});

function getJSONData(){
    setTimeout("getJSONData()", 24000);
    $.getJSON('?act=rt&callback=?', displayData);
}

function displayData(dataJSON)
{
    $("#randpic img").fadeOut();
    $("#randpic img").attr('src', dataJSON.randpic);
    $("#randpic img").fadeIn();
}
```

You can delete the css's rule and onload on your HTML, normally will be works ;)

Comment: Hi mate, your code seems to be working. Thanks. Just one small problem, if the picture hasn't been loaded before (i.e. not in the browser cache), there will be no effect. But I guess that has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the following from the server (the `onload` won't work because this is only called when the page has finished loading):

```
<img alt="Hi" src="images/banner5.jpg" />
```

Then change your displayData method to:

```
function displayData(dataJSON)
{
    $("#randpic").html(dataJSON.randpic);
    $("#randpic img").css('opacity', '1');
}
```

Comment: Ohhh sorry I not seen CSS rule which he is setting :)

Comment: Not sure if you saw the answer before the edit or not? The css will set the image to opacity:0; when it's loaded in to the div. Setting the opacity via the javascript will kick off the transition defined in the css.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){getJSONData();});

    function getJSONData()
    {
       setTimeout("getJSONData()", 24000);
       $.getJSON('?act=rt&callback=?', displayData1);
    }
    function displayData1(data){
      $('#randpic').fadeOut(500);
      setTimeout('displayData('+data+')', 500);
    } 
    function displayData(dataJSON)
    {
       $("#randpic").html(dataJSON.randpic).fadeIn(500);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Vishnu, thanks for the advice. But could you please advise what the data in displayData1(data) mean?

Comment: data in displayData1 is your JSON response